# GRE word frequency

Tags: gre

I was studying GRE sample questions, and thanks to google English meaning bar it shows the "Use over time for..." that word. After seeing a lot plots, I found a pattern. Most of them has been least used in last decade.

My question is why would words which have less usage now-a-days are being asked more frequently in GRE exam?

Comment: Makes for harder questions, right? Older material has the florid language the College Board loves to test you on. Read the classics, and you will learn that vocabulary in context. Read Lady Chatterley's Lover and don't tell your mother.

Comment: 1) If you're speaking of the counts Google gives at the top of its definitions, those are unreliable. 2) The GRE is supposed to test your ability to handle sophisticated academic language, not conversational language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the  frequency of occurrence of questions in some exam has nothing whatsoever to do with SE ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with a limited amount of time.

Words with high frequency in the last decade are probably words that are commonly known. If the GRE is supposed to test vocabulary, it makes sense to me to prioritize testing on words that MIGHT be used, but with less frequency.